# moving focus over sequential editText controls in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have 4 editText

I want the user to set one digit in each of them sequentially.

how would you suggest enumerating the controls?

Is there any attribute I can override which will save the next editText control's id?

Comment: add a text watcher, and check if the edittext.gettext().tostring().length()>0 and then request focus on the next edittext.